# Python scraping with Selenium and Beautifulsoup can't extract nested tag, error object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I can't extract nested tag with find_next, find_children, or find_next_siblings, result in either TypeError: can only concatenate str(not"Tag")to str or object is not callable, any way to extract a nested tag? Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code? Usually it's better to apply some of the code as text and not picture. Here you can read some on the topic.  
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557  
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such method `find_children` in the [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-using-tag-names), that is why you are getting a `object is not callable` error. However, you can extract the weight and weight_scale using `contents[0]` instead of having to rely on a loop, considering this is a fixed webpage html and won't change soon.

Note that I chose to use the `requests` library to make the request to the webpage and grab the HTML, but you can try running your code with PhantomJS.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://stats.nba.com/player/1629121/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

height_div = soup.find('div', string='HT')
height = height_div.find_next().contents[0]

weight_div = soup.find('div', string='WT')
weight = weight_div.find_next().contents[0].strip()
weight_scale = weight_div.find_next().contents[1].contents[0]

age_div = soup.find('div', string='AGE')
age = age_div.find_next().contents[0]

print(height)
print(f"{weight} {weight_scale}")
print(age)
```

If you still want to try other methods, you can check the documentation I linked before.

Comment: @S.Y also please check the links commented by [@akane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11635356/akane). I had to go through the images instead of just copying your code.